# How to apply Chinese Remainder Theorem to polynomials

Tags: polynomials, chinese-remainder-theorem, euclidean-algorithm

> **QUESTION:** Find a polynomial $p(x)$ that simultaneously has both the following properties.
>
> $(i)$ When $p(x)$ is divided by $x^{100}$ the remainder is the constant polynomial $1.$
>
> $(ii)$ When $p(x)$ is divided by $(x − 2)^3$ the remainder is the constant polynomial $2.$

---

**MY APPROACH:** I recently came to know about the Chinese Remainder Theorem, and was literally amazed by it's wide variety of applications. Now the questions I dealt with so far were composed of numbers and linear congruences. This is the first time I have come across a question that deals with polynomials. I know there are other ways to solve this problem, but I am particularly interested in solving it with the aid of the Chinese Remainder Theorem. How is that theorem applied to polynomials, like this one?

Moreover I have examined that $x^{100}$ and $(x-2)^3$ are *coprime* to each other. So it ensures that the theorem can be applied safely.

> Pardon me, this question has been asked before. But the solution provided was not complete. It did not show the full *process* as to how to do the sum. All I need is one answer where the full *method* to tackle with polynomials using the CRT is done (consider this question, for instance).

A detailed answer will be very much helpful in this regard.
Also it will be great if you can suggest me some texts or reference from where I can learn how to apply CRT on polynomials..

Thank you so much.

Answer (score 1):

ADDED: What I get is that , for some $n$  which will eventually be set to 100, that
$$ x^n \left(\frac{n^2 + n}{2} x^2 - (2n^2 + 4n)x + (2n^2 + 6n + 4) \right) - 2^{n+2}  $$
is divisible by $(x-2)^3$

This can be confirmed by evaluating the function and its first derivative and its second derivative at $x=2$  and showing that each results in zero.

There are tricks for doing this rapidly in contests, perhaps at the previous question you linked.

ORIGINAL:
Here are Bezout identities for $x^n$ and $(x-2)^3$  for $n=3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10.$ Seem to be some patterns, especially the denominator needed is always a power of $2.$
 $$  \left(   x^{3}  \right)  \left(   \frac{ 3 x^{2}  - 15 x  + 20 }{ 16 }  \right)  -  \left(   x^{3}  - 6 x^{2}  + 12 x  - 8 \right)  \left(   \frac{ 3 x^{2}  + 3 x  + 2 }{ 16 }  \right)  =  \left( 1  \right)  $$
$$  $$
$$  \left(   x^{4}  \right)  \left(   \frac{ 5 x^{2}  - 24 x  + 30 }{ 32 }  \right)  -  \left(   x^{3}  - 6 x^{2}  + 12 x  - 8 \right)  \left(   \frac{ 5 x^{3}  + 6 x^{2}  + 6 x  + 4 }{ 32 }  \right)  =  \left( 1  \right)  $$ 
$$  $$
 $$  \left(   x^{5}  \right)  \left(   \frac{ 15 x^{2}  - 70 x  + 84 }{ 128 }  \right)  -  \left(   x^{3}  - 6 x^{2}  + 12 x  - 8 \right)  \left(   \frac{ 15 x^{4}  + 20 x^{3}  + 24 x^{2}  + 24 x  + 16 }{ 128 }  \right)  =  \left( 1  \right)  $$
$$ $$
 $$  \left(   x^{6}  \right)  \left(   \frac{ 21 x^{2}  - 96 x  + 112 }{ 256 }  \right)  -  \left(   x^{3}  - 6 x^{2}  + 12 x  - 8 \right)  \left(   \frac{ 21 x^{5}  + 30 x^{4}  + 40 x^{3}  + 48 x^{2}  + 48 x  + 32 }{ 256 }  \right)  =  \left( 1  \right)  $$
$$  $$
 $$  \left(   x^{7}  \right)  \left(   \frac{ 14 x^{2}  - 63 x  + 72 }{ 256 }  \right)  -  \left(   x^{3}  - 6 x^{2}  + 12 x  - 8 \right)  \left(   \frac{ 14 x^{6}  + 21 x^{5}  + 30 x^{4}  + 40 x^{3}  + 48 x^{2}  + 48 x  + 32 }{ 256 }  \right)  =  \left( 1  \right)  $$ 
$$  $$
 $$  \left(   x^{8}  \right)  \left(   \frac{ 9 x^{2}  - 40 x  + 45 }{ 256 }  \right)  -  \left(   x^{3}  - 6 x^{2}  + 12 x  - 8 \right)  \left(   \frac{ 9 x^{7}  + 14 x^{6}  + 21 x^{5}  + 30 x^{4}  + 40 x^{3}  + 48 x^{2}  + 48 x  + 32 }{ 256 }  \right)  =  \left( 1  \right)  $$ 
$$  $$
 $$  \left(   x^{9}  \right)  \left(   \frac{ 45 x^{2}  - 198 x  + 220 }{ 2048 }  \right)  -  \left(   x^{3}  - 6 x^{2}  + 12 x  - 8 \right)  \left(   \frac{ 45 x^{8}  + 72 x^{7}  + 112 x^{6}  + 168 x^{5}  + 240 x^{4}  + 320 x^{3}  + 384 x^{2}  + 384 x  + 256 }{ 2048 }  \right)  =  \left( 1  \right)  $$
$$  $$
 $$  \left(   x^{10}  \right)  \left(   \frac{ 55 x^{2}  - 240 x  + 264 }{ 4096 }  \right)  -  \left(   x^{3}  - 6 x^{2}  + 12 x  - 8 \right)  \left(   \frac{ 55 x^{9}  + 90 x^{8}  + 144 x^{7}  + 224 x^{6}  + 336 x^{5}  + 480 x^{4}  + 640 x^{3}  + 768 x^{2}  + 768 x  + 512 }{ 4096 }  \right)  =  \left( 1  \right)  $$
$$  $$

Comment: Woah, this is really some big calculation.. I am yet to know about bezout identities.. thank you for your help though.. :)

Comment: @StrangerForever   given coprime elements $p,q$, a Bezout identity is just a new pair $r,s$ such that $pr+qs = 1,$  arrived at by an Extended Euclidean Algorithm.  For polynomials,  we allow constant outcome other than $1;$ in any of these, multiply everything by the evident denominator

Comment: Can you suggest me a text where I can read about extended Euclidean algorithm in detail.. I came across the Euclidean division algorithm, and that was pretty interesting.. but I am yet to learn about the extension..

Comment: @StrangerForever  not sure, first go through the 73 posts I found with both "tags" euclidean-algorithm  and polynomials:  https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/euclidean-algorithm+polynomials   I have already checked my original function and its first derivative, the pattern is looking very good. I put it at the top of the answer.